# Task failed with an exception keep occuring when trying to execute react native from templates

Tags: react-native

I am a very beginner with react native and as part of my learning I tried to use below boilerplate template

https://thecodingmachine.github.io/react-native-boilerplate/

I have installed and while executing using

npx react-native run-android

Its straight away failing at terminal and saying Build Failed and in the details

I can see 4 errors like this

```
FAILURE: Build completed with 4 failures.

1: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-gesture-handler:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

2: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
java.lang.StackOverflowError (no error message)

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

3: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-screens:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details

* Try:
> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.
==============================================================================

4: Task failed with an exception.
-----------
* What went wrong:
Execution failed for task ':react-native-safe-area-context:compileDebugKotlin'.
> A failure occurred while executing org.jetbrains.kotlin.compilerRunner.GradleCompilerRunnerWithWorkers$GradleKotlinCompilerWorkAction
   > Compilation error. See log for more details
```

Below my build.gradle contents

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    ext {
        buildToolsVersion = "33.0.0"
        minSdkVersion = 21
        compileSdkVersion = 33
        targetSdkVersion = 33

        // We use NDK 23 which has both M1 support and is the side-by-side NDK version from AGP.
        ndkVersion = "23.1.7779620"
    }
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.3.1")
        classpath("com.facebook.react:react-native-gradle-plugin")
    }
}
```

Same time if I am not using any templates I am able to execute the app in my phone.

Please help

Below my package.json

```
{
  "name": "Ocms",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "android": "react-native run-android",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios",
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "start": "react-native start",
    "test": "jest",
    "type-check": "tsc",
    "test:report": "jest --collectCoverage --coverageDirectory=\"./coverage\" --ci --reporters=default --reporters=jest-junit --coverage",
    "pod-install": "cd ios && RCT_NEW_ARCH_ENABLED=1 bundle exec pod install && cd .."
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.8",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.5.7",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.1.6",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.3.16",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.9.3",
    "i18next": "^22.4.10",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^12.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.9.0",
    "react-native-mmkv": "^2.6.2",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^3.0.2",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.5.0",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.20.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.5",
    "redux-persist": "^6.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.20.0",
    "@react-native-community/eslint-config": "^3.2.0",
    "@react-navigation/devtools": "^6.0.18",
    "@testing-library/jest-native": "^5.4.2",
    "@testing-library/react-native": "^12.0.0",
    "@tsconfig/react-native": "^2.0.2",
    "@types/jest": "^29.4.0",
    "@types/node": "^18.14.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "^29.2.1",
    "babel-plugin-inline-dotenv": "^1.7.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^5.0.0",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.6.0",
    "dotenv": "^16.0.3",
    "eslint": "^8.19.0",
    "jest": "^29.2.1",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-flipper": "^0.182.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "18.2.0",
    "redux-flipper": "^2.0.2",
    "typescript": "4.8.4"
  }
}
```